# How to disassemble an electron app without having access to its asar file

Tags: windows, electron, disassembly, decompiling, unpack

I know I can disassemble electron apps that have an `asar` file or package [as said here](https://medium.com/how-to-electron/how-to-get-source-code-of-any-electron-application-cbb5c7726c37). But I have installed an app (that seems to be built with electron) and this application does not have asar file in it.

This is the picture of directory of the application:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eG9A4.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKvSC.png

As you see there is not `resources` folder and there is only one `Soroush.exe` file which seems to have all the stuff that the application needs to run by itself.

How to disassemble this kind of apps (Electrons w/o ASAR)?